# Can I put a LESS/Sass variable in an Angular TypeScript component?

Tags: angular, sass, less

Can I put some LESS/Sass variable in an Angular TypeScript component?

For example:

```
animations: [
    trigger('dialog', [
      state('*', style({
        transform: 'translate(unit(@var1, px), unit(@var2, px))',
        top: 'unit(@var3, px)',
        height: 'unit(@var4, px)'
```

Current code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'animationDialog', 
  templateUrl: './animationDialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css'], 
  animations: [
    trigger('dialog', [
      state('*', style({
        transform: 'translate(20px, 20px)',
        top: '20px',
        height: '20px'
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?
https://github.com/davidkpiano/sassport